# How to lookup the content of an Excel file (in column A) in a Word file and add a comment on that word with the content of column B?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, macros

First I would like to say that I have basic knowledge of VBA.

I am currently trying to create a macro in Word that I would like to link to an opened Excel file and search for a word from column A in the opened Word file. Then I would like to make the macro place a comment on that word in Word and insert the content of column B of the Excel file.

I have tried to combine different lines of code together from different source but I do not seem to be able to make it work.

Is there anyone on here that knows how to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

I have the following code for adding the comment (but that is not linked to the excel file);

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

Dim range As range
Set range = ActiveDocument.Content

Do While range.Find.Execute("XXXXXX") = True
ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range, "YYYYYY"
Loop
```

and the following peace of code that finds the content of column A and currently replaces it with the content of column B.

```
Dim ws As Activesheet, msWord As Object, itm As range

Set ws = Activesheet
Set msWord = ActiveDocument.Content

With msWord ' cant figure out how to change this so it uses the currently open Word file.
    .Visible = True
    .Documents.Open "F:\Test folder\TestFolder\Test.docx"
    .Activate

    With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

            .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col A

            .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2  'Replacements from col B

            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False

            .Execute Replace:=2     'I guess this should be replaced with the code that places the text YYYYYY as a comment on the text XXXXXX?
        Next
    End With
    .Quit SaveChanges:=True
End With
```

Comment: please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1439556/edit) to include the code you have as well as details on how it fails to achieve the desired result

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have included the code I have

Comment: You're right that you copy between Excel and Word with a macro. Here an important hint: Open Word. Open the Visual Basic Editor. Click Tools > References. Scroll down and select "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library." With that reference, the Word macro can include Excel objects, such as Worksheet. 

Do I understand the arrangement? Excel has two columns, A with terms and B with notes. The Word macro would search a document for every term in column A and add the note from column B as a comment.

Comment: @scenopraphy Thnx! I have added the Excel object library. Indeed that is the arrangement.

Comment: @Rvdb8 Did you make any further progress? Do you need any further help?